# clustering semantically related words from a list of words

Tags: nlp, semantics, cpu-word, text-mining, wordnet

I have a word list containing about 30000 **unique** words.
I would like to group this list of words based on how similar these words tend to be.
Can I create a ontology tree using this list and with possibly with the help of WordNet?

So essentially what I want to do is aggregate these words in some meaningful way to reduce the size of the list.
 What kind of techniques can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) to make a first step towards clustering these words according to their SYNSET. In addition to 'same meaning' and 'opposite meaning' Wordnet also includes 'part of' relationships.  Following these relationships for the word 'beer' for example visits all of these containing synsets: Brew1, Alcohol1, Drug_of_abuse1, Drug1, Agent3, Substance7, Matter3, Physical_entity1, Entity1, Causal_agent1, Beverage1, Liquid1, Fluid1, Substance1, Part1, Relation1, Abstraction6, Food1.

But ... it will depend on what kind of words you have as to how many you will find in Wordnet. It doesn't include verb tenses and it doesn't have a very large or very modern set of proper nouns. If you 30,000 words are adjectives and nouns it should do quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yeah so in my case I have pronouns mostly names of people. First name and last name is separated as two words, and I would like to combine them to form a single word. I tried some online WordNet similarity tools but seems like WordNet is not a solution. But if I could use Wikipedia it would be a very good solution as it's uptodate. Do you know any tools I can use here which is based on Wikipedia?

Comment: For *proper nouns*, try DBPedia or one of the other Wikipedia derived datasets.